# Re-Submitting a failed Task in an ActionBlock

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am using an action block that looks something like this:

```
ActionBlock<Tuple<string,byte[],string>> ab  = 
    new ActionBlock<Tuple<string,string,string>>(item => {
            service.DoSomeAction(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3);
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
        });

foreach(var item in Items) {
    ab.Post(new Tuple<string,string,string>(item.a, item.b, item.c));
}

ab.Complete();
ab.Completion.Wait();
```

My issue is that `service.DoSomeAction()` can fail due to network load and I am wondering if ActionBlock has a mechanism to reque the task.

I can certainly add a try/catch block around that call and have the catch block wait/retry a few times before rethrowing the exception. What I am looking for is to just call `ab.Post()` with the same parameters. My issue is I am already calling `ab.Complete()`. Is it possible to wait on an ActionBlock without calling `ab.Complete()`. Is there a better tool I could be using for the job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to wait on an ActionBlock without calling `ab.Complete()`.

Yes, just don't call it and directly go to `ab.Completion.Wait();` (*Side note*: you should use `await ab.Completion;` if possible), **BUT** someone else will need to call `ab.Complete()` then as otherwise it would wait indefinetily as `ab.Completion` will never complete.

**BUT** why don't you want to use a "try/catch/retry" logic inside your action? IMO this would be the better approach.
E.g. using [`TransientFaultHandling.Core`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TransientFaultHandling.Core) you could do something like:

```
var retry = new RetryPolicy(ErrorDetectionStrategy.On<Exception>(), // see http://pastebin.com/6tmQbkj4
                            3, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));     
ActionBlock<Tuple<string,byte[],string>> ab  = 
    new ActionBlock<Tuple<string,string,string>>(item => 
        retry.ExecuteAction(() => service.Action(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3)),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
        });
```

Comment: The reason why I don't want that logic inside, is because different task use up different amount of resources. I am hoping by re-posting the same job, it will be executed at a sufficiently later time to free up whatever resources might have caused it to fail. But I am still weighing the pros/cons of doing it one way or another. I am just trying to see if this is actually possible, or if there is another simpler/easier solution that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `ActionBlock`, could you just use the `Parallel` class instead?

Something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Items, item =>
{
    bool succeeded = false;
    while(!succeeded)
    {
        try
        {
            service.DoSomeAction(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3);
            succeeded = true;
        }
        catch(MyException) //the expected Exception, let others get thrown
        {
        }
    }
});
```